# GCD queue with completion block that runs sequentially

Tags: objective-c

I have code that needed to be run in sequentially, but most answer that I've searched doesn't include the case where it has a completion block. For example:

```
//global variable
dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.my.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL); 
    
-(void)executeTask:(int)taskNum{
    dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
            //TIME CONSUMING TASK
            [self doTask:taskNum withCompletion:^{
                  NSLog(@"completed task number: %d", taskNum);
            }];
        }); 
}

-(void)startTask:(int)taskNum{
    [self executeTask:taskNum];
}
```

`startTask:` may be called multiple times, and it shall run sequentially once the completion handler of the previous task is completed.

Which means, if `startTask:` gets called 5 times, in the order of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`,
the expected output would be:

```
completed task number: 1
completed task number: 2
completed task number: 3
completed task number: 4
completed task number: 5
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `-doTask:withCompletion:` run synchronously?

Comment: You can achieve that by using concurrent `NSOperation`'s and `NSOperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to 1. You can find code snippets how to create concurrent operations in this manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1

Comment: What output does the code you have shown produce? The answer to your question depends on the nature of `doTask:` and what control you have over that nature.

Comment: Here you would call the completion handler in a ```sync``` fashion. Thus if this runs on e.g. @Cy-4AH's queue you'd use something like ```dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ { ,,, } )``` when done.